# Defining a function as transformation of open sets

Tags: general-topology, functions

In a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is it true that a function $f$ is uniquely defined if we define $f$ as transformation of open sets in $X$?

My proof would be like follows (by contradiction)

Suppose $f,g$ are such that for each $\mathcal{O} \in \tau$ we have
$f(\mathcal{O}) = g(\mathcal{O})$, pick $x \in X$, and assume $f(x) \neq g(x)$.

Let $\mathcal{O}_0 \subset \mathcal{O}$ an open set containing $x$ and pick $x_1 \neq x$ in $\mathcal{O}_0$. If we iterate we can construct a sequence of open sets $\mathcal{O}_k$ such that

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\mathcal{O}_k \subset\mathcal{O}_{k+1} \\
x \in \mathcal{O}_k \; \forall k \\
x_k \in O_{k-1} - \mathcal{O}_k
\end{array}
$$

such a sequence converges to $x$, if we assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous then they will converge to the same point, since the for all $k$ we have $f(\mathcal{O}_k) = g(\mathcal{O}_k)$.

Is it correct?

Comment: How do you prove $f(X - \left\{ x \right\}) = g(X - \left\{ x \right\}) \Rightarrow X - f(\left\{ x \right\}) = X - g(\left\{ x \right\})$?

Comment: Why is $\{x\}$ closed?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is no.

Comment: @Randall let's say that he works in T1 spaces... The implication I pointed out is still wrong. As is the general statement

Comment: Updated my post. Aren't singletons closed sets? At least in Haussdorf spaces.

Comment: @Federico isn't $f(X - A) = X - f(A)$?

Comment: Take $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R:x\mapsto x^2$ and $x_0=1$. Then $f(\mathbb R\setminus\{x_0\})=[0,\infty)$, but $f(\mathbb R)\setminus f(\{x_0\})=[0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: Ok, then I don't have a clue. I think I can use sequences to prove it though, or is there a quicker way?

Comment: Why prove it if it may be false?

Comment: Is it false then?

Comment: It *could* be true for all I know (with the Hausdorff assumption), but it's not at all clear to me that it is.  Therefore, I'm not trying to prove it:  I'm investigating for counterexamples first, then seeing if that leads me to either (a) a direction for a proof or (b) a refinement toward a counterexample.  I'm keeping an open mind.

Comment: Fair enough, do you reckon using the sequence argument I'm suggesting can lead me to anything? (I'm trying to work out the details).

Comment: My gut reaction is that there is either a really obvious counterexample or a bizarre non-second-countable counterexample. I don't think it's true, but I can't prove that I'm right.  If I were going to try to prove it, I would use sequences.

Comment: I gave it another go, I'm not 100% convinced. I restricted to continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $Y$ is a Hausdorff space.  Suppose that $f,g : X \to Y$ are continuous maps for which $f(\mathcal{O}) = g(\mathcal{O})$ for all open $\mathcal{O}$ in $X$.  We claim that $f=g$.

Suppose to the contrary that there is a point $a \in X$ with $f(a) \neq g(a)$.  As $Y$ is Hausdorff, we may separate these points:  take disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ containing $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ respectively.  From $f(a) \in U$ we have $a \in f^{-1}(U)$, which is an open set.  Hence $g(a) \in g(f^{-1}(U))$.  But by hypothesis, this says $g(a) \in f(f^{-1}(U))$.  But $f(f^{-1}(U)) \subseteq U$, so we have $g(a) \in U$, which contradicts the disjointness of $U$ and $V$.

Edit:  A similar argument works in the case that $Y$ is only $T_0$. The definition there is that $Y$ is $T_0$ if for all points $y_1 \neq y_2$ in $Y$ there is an open set $U$ containing one point but not the other (and you don't have control over which).  If we can enclose $f(a)$ in an open set $U$ not containing $g(a)$ then run the same argument above.  You obtain the same contradiction.  If not, then we can enclose $g(a)$ in an open set that doesn't contain $f(a)$ and you run the symmetric argument (flip the roles of $f$ and $g$) and still get the same contradiction.

Comment: So it is true, we can define functions by how they acts on opensets (with some assumptions).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why my sequence argument doesn't work?

Comment: @user8469759  It doesn't work because that sequence need not converge.